# Dynamic set textarea height based on string length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code which I can't solve the part `this.scrollHeight...`.
The `data.address` could be a short or long string. So my intention is to dynamic set the height of the `textarea` to fully display the text within but I can't figure out how to do that using code below.

`$('#myAddress').val(data.address).css('height', this.scrollHeight + this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set it to scrollHeight.

```
$("#myAddress").height( $("#myAddress")[0].scrollHeight );
```

[**DEMO on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o75ye8wv/)

Comment: Is it possible to replace the 2nd $(‘#myAddress’) with this?

Comment: No. In this usecase, no.

Comment: Hi, there is a problem. The height keep on increasing whenever I trigger this line.

Comment: This line of code is basically adjusting textarea height based on the text within, which is what you've asked. I'm not sure what's wrong there, given your question.